# Number ascending value in multiple JSON files visual studio

Tags: json, visual-studio

I have like a 1000 JSON files looks like this

**1.json**

```
{

"Address": "Building #1"

}

I need to fill the rest of the files with ascending value like the following

**3.json**

{

"Address": "Building #3"

}

**500.json**

{

"Address": "Building #500"

}
```

Is it possible using visual studio? And if I want it to start with Building #200 instead of Building #1 how to do it?

if it can be done with visual studio, it will help me a lot as changing it manually will take so much time.